# Creating a "solver" loop in Excel to run a minimizing problem

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on my master thesis and need to run the solver function in excel on around 300 data data point.

Attached please find the code that I need to run the solver only for line 35 in my excel sheet. My objective function is stated in cell "O" by changing the values in cell G and H. As I have to run the same analysis multiple times, I don't want to solve each line individually as  it would take my days.

Can someone pleas help me how I can implement a loop in which VBA solves all objective cells starting from Line 4 until line 283.

```
Sub FinalMinimizing()  
    'FinalMinimizing Macro
    SolverOk SetCell:="$O$35", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$35:$H$35", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$O$35", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$35:$H$35", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you are wanting to vary the row number like so?

```
Sub FinalMinimizing()

Dim r As Long

For r = 4 To 283
    SolverOk SetCell:="$O$" & r, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$" & r & ":$H$" & r, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$O$" & r, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$" & r & ":$H$" & r, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
Next r

End Sub
```